# Use ffmpeg to send custom header for RTSP session

Tags: ffmpeg, rtsp, onvif

I am trying to use the ffmpeg library (not the command line) to open an RTSP stream and push that stream to a server. In ONVIF parlance, this is a `backchannel` (for sending audio to a camera).

Where I am stuck is in sending a custom header (`Require: ...`) with the `DESCRIBE` command, and being able to handle the reply.

Is there a way to do this with ffmpeg?

```
DESCRIBE rtsp://192.168.0.1 RTSP/1.0 CSeq: 1
User-Agent: ONVIF Rtsp client Accept: application/sdp
Require: www.onvif.org/ver20/backchannel
```

I noticed in `rtsp.c` that there are various `*_rtsp_send_cmd_*()` functions that look interesting, but they all appear to be private to the library.

Comment: Not sure if it is possible with ffmpeg but I have done it with Live555 without any issues. Its required since the ONVIF spec has mandatory additional headers to achieve Onvif S compliance.

Comment: I also wanted to add headers and ended up using https://github.com/marss/aiortsp/ in Python but doing the decoding with ffmpeg.